# Segmentation fault in serialize function

Tags: c, serialization

The problem is in the MSG variable. Each message can have a size that can change, so the payload_len variable. I can not identify the error in the code.
All my attempts have resulted in "Segmentation fault".

**PKG**

```
typedef struct pkg{
    uint32_t payload_len;
    uint32_t psecret;
    uint16_t step;
    uint16_t student_num;
    char* msg;
}Pkg;
```

**construct funtion**

```
Pkg* constructPKG(int payload_len, int psecret, short step, char* msg){

    Pkg* pkgS = (Pkg*) malloc(sizeof(Pkg));
    pkgS->payload_len = payload_len;
    pkgS->psecret = psecret;
    pkgS->step = step;
    pkgS->student_num = STUDENT_NUM;
    pkgS->msg=msg;
    return pkgS;
}
```

**Serialize function**

```
void serialize(Pkg* pkgS, char *data){
    uint32_t temp_32;
    uint16_t temp_16;

    temp_32 = htonl(pkgS->payload_len);
    memcpy(&data[0], &temp_32, sizeof(temp_32));

    temp_32 = htonl(pkgS->psecret);
    memcpy(&data[4], &temp_32, sizeof(temp_32));

    temp_16 = htons(pkgS->step);
    memcpy(&data[8], &temp_16, sizeof(temp_16));

    temp_16 = htons(pkgS->student_num);
    memcpy(&data[10], &temp_16, sizeof(temp_16));

    int x = pkgS->payload_len;
    char msg[x];
    memcpy(&data[12], &pkgS->msg,sizeof(msg));

}
```

**Deserialize function**

```
void deserialize(char *data, Pkg* pkgs){
    uint32_t temp_32;
    uint16_t temp_16;


    memcpy(&temp_32, &data[0], sizeof(temp_32));
    pkgs->payload_len=ntohl(temp_32);

    memcpy(&temp_32, &data[4], sizeof(temp_32));
    pkgs->psecret=ntohl(temp_32);

    memcpy(&temp_16, &data[8], sizeof(temp_16));
    pkgs->step=ntohs(temp_16);

    memcpy(&temp_16, &data[10], sizeof(temp_16));
    pkgs->student_num=ntohs(temp_16);

    int x = pkgs->payload_len;
    char msg[x];
    memcpy(&pkgs->msg[0], &data[12], sizeof(msg));
}
```

**Print function**

```
void printPkg(Pkg* pkgS){
    printf("Payload_len: %d\n",pkgS->payload_len);
    printf("Psecret: %d\n",pkgS->psecret);
    printf("Step: %d\n",pkgS->step);
    printf("Student_num: %d\n",pkgS->student_num);
    printf("MSG: %s\n",pkgS->msg);
}
```

Comment: please show the code where you resever memory for `pkgS->msg` before calling deserialize (or serialize); the `construction` just assigns parameter `msg`...

Comment: ` char *hello="Hello World";
 char *data;
 Pkg *x = constructPKG(strlen(hello), 12, 2, hello);
 Pkg *y = constructPKG(0, 0, 0, NULL);`

Comment: @JefersonJuliani Put code in the question, not comments.

Comment: You don't need the `msg` variable. `sizeof(msg)` is the same as `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the `msg` pointer, not the data that it points to. But you're using the length of the payload, so you're accessing outside the `struct` if `payload_len > sizeof(char*)`.

Change

```
int x = pkgS->payload_len;
char msg[x];
memcpy(&data[12], &pkgS->msg,sizeof(msg));
```

to

```
char msg[x];
memcpy(&data[12], pkgS->msg, pgkS->payload_len);
```

And in the `deserialize()` function, you need to allocate space for `msg` before copying to it. Change:

```
int x = pkgs->payload_len;
char msg[x];
memcpy(&pkgs->msg[0], &data[12], sizeof(msg));
```

to

```
pkgs->msg = malloc(pkgs->payload_len);
memcpy(pkgs->msg, &data[12], pkgs->payload_len);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code that look suspicious:

First, in your serialize function, you pass the address of a pointer (not the pointer value) to `memcpy`. This will lead to undefined behaviour (reading from memory that does not belong to a valid object. Change

```
int x = pkgS->payload_len;
char msg[x];
memcpy(&data[12], &pkgS->msg,sizeof(msg));
```

to ...

```
memcpy(&data[12], pkgS->msg, pkgS->payload_len);
```

Second, in deserialize, you copy into `pkgs->msg`, but it seems that you did not have reserved memory for it (in the comment, you state that you pass `NULL` to the `construct`-function. Instead of

```
int x = pkgs->payload_len;
char msg[x];
memcpy(&pkgs->msg[0], &data[12], sizeof(msg));
```

Write

```
pkgs->msg = malloc(pkgs->payload_len);
memcpy(&pkgs->msg[0], &data[12], pkgs->payload_len);
```